# Convert Road layer shapefile into a graph

Tags: qgis, python, shapefile, astar

I'm going to use Astar algorithm to find a path between two selected points.And I used the following code for that.Is there any way I could convert my Road Layer shapefile into a graph, which can be use in this function? I'm new to QGIS and please help me to find a solution to this problem.

```
def astarSearch(self, graphAstar, current, end):
    openSet = set()
    openHeap = []
    closedSet = set()

    def retracePath(c):
        path = [c]
        while c.parent is not None:
                c = c.parent
                path.append(c)
        path.reverse()
        return path

    openSet.add(current)
    openHeap.append((0,current))
    while openSet:
    print "come2"
        current = heapq.heappop(openHeap)[1]
        if current == end:
        print "come3"                   
        return retracePath(current)
        openSet.remove(current)
        closedSet.add(current)
        for tile in graphAstar[current]:
        print "come4"
                if tile not in closedSet:
                    tile.H = (abs(end.x-tile.x)+abs(end.y-tile.y))*10 
                    if tile not in openSet:
                            openSet.add(tile)
                            heapq.heappush(openHeap, (tile.H,tile))
                    tile.parent = current
    return []
```

Comment: Please post your code again with correct indentation.

Comment: You are missing the basic for A*. There is a case that a node is on the OpenList already and later you find a shorter path for that node. In that case the position of the node in the priority queue should be improved. This operation is called DecreaseKey and your code does not take care of it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Networkx library.

http://networkx.github.io

It can read shapefiles. Ex:

```
import networkx

graph = networkx.read_shp("path/to/your/shapefile.shp")
```

Now you can use your graph:

```
print graph.nodes()

[(X.X, Y.Y), (X.X, Y.Y)...]
```

There are also few alghoritms implemented: Dijkstra, Bellman-Ford, A*

http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/algorithms.shortest_paths.html

Comment: I used networkx. But it always returned '[]' (according to my code) for me. why is that?

Comment: Please tell me a way except networkx, because it's not working for me..